# Passing data from jsp page to action class using struts upon clicking a href link

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a JSP page wherein I am displaying some text in the form of a link.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 pull-left">
      <a href="getCityDetails.action" name = "cityName"><s:property value="cityName" /></a>
        </div>
```

Wherein I am fetching the city Name from some particular java class file through an action.

When I click the text I want it to redirect to the action getCityDetails.action, which in turn calls some method of another java class file. But along with this, I want to **pass data** into the action, that is **the text** that I have clicked. What changes should I make to accommodate this behaviour?

Comment: append the data in url  `getCityDetails.action?parameterName=value`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the data as a query parameter:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 pull-left">
  <a href="getCityDetails.action?cityname=<s:property value="cityName" />" name = "cityName"><s:property value="cityName" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I add something to the action declared in my struts file as well?

Comment: you might have trouble in Nested double Quotes

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`<s:url>`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/url.html) tag to build an action URL:

```xml
<s:url value="getCityDetails.action" var="url">
    <s:param name="cityName" value="%{cityName}" />
</s:url>
```

then use it in a standard `<a>`:

```xml
<a href="<s:property value="%{#url}"/>">
    <s:property value="cityName" />
</a>
```

or in an [`<s:a>`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/a.html):

```xml
<s:a href="%{url}">
    <s:property value="cityName" />
</s:a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Parameter within the URL

**Try This**

```
 <a href="getCityDetails.action?paramToPassToAction=Value" name = "cityName"><s:property value="cityName" /></a>
```